Module warning (browser--external
I'm working on a software system for a website with my friend and when I pulled his latest work I suddenly got a lots of warnings at the console and I don't know why and how to solve it
here's a screenshot of the console
I tried to check any changes at the dependencies but nothing has changed and it didn't work

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
